# Backbone call fetch on every get

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have setup a basic modal where I can call `fetch()` and the model will update. However, I want `fetch()` to be called every time you attempt to access an attribute.

so I have something like this

```
get: function () {
    this.fetch()
    Backbone.Model.prototype.get.call(this, attr);
}
```

This clearly wont work as this.fetch() is asynchronous. Is there a way to wait for fetch, or implement this concept in a better way

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you should be overwriting the get method. You might be better off creating an async version, and returning a deferred object from it.

Fetch is async, and there is no way around that, so you will have to do this in an async fashion.

Something like this might work:

```
getAsync: function(attribute){
  var dfd = $.Deferred(), model = this;
  this.fetch().done(function(){
    dfd.resolve(model.get(attribute));
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}
```

and then you'd use it like this:

```
model.getAsync(field).done(function(value){
  console.log(field + " was " + value)
});
```

(seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/FBp6h/)

Comment: "*Fetch is async, and there is no way around that*", what about setting `{async: false}`?

Comment: Well it *is* a solution, so I don't see the point in saying there's no way around. And it most definitely can be a solution to his strange desire of fetching everytime he uses `get` (otherwise he'll have fun debugging I guess, and other surprises).